# lualatex running a single command with popen (and showing its output in the document)

Tags: luatex

On Linux/Debian/Sid, inside any `git` repository, the following pipeline gives some git commit id:

```
git log --format=oneline -1 --abbrev=16 --abbrev-commit -q | cut -d' ' -f1
```

for example, in one directory, it outputs `03aa650c1bbd20c3`. I want to show that string in my LuaLaTeX document.

However, with the following `lx.tex` file:

```
% file lx.tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
  pip=io.popen("git log --format=oneline -1 --abbrev=16 --abbrev-commit -q | cut -d' ' -f1")
  gitid=pip:read("l")
  pip:close()
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\mygitid}{\luadirect{tex.print(gitid)}}

The gitid is \mygitid
\end{document}
```

that I process with `lualatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --halt-on-error lx` I am getting an error

```
% lualatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --halt-on-error lx
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) 
 system commands enabled.
(./lx.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.594 seconds (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty)))
(./lx.aux)[\directlua]:2: bad argument #1 to 'read' (invalid option)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'read'
    [\directlua]:2: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }

l.8 \end{luacode*}


 350 words of node memory still in use:
   1 hlist, 1 rule, 1 dir, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 3 attribute, 45 glue_spec, 3 attrib
ute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:8,3:1,4:1,5:4,7:2,8:1,9:3
./lx.tex:8:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on lx.log.
```

But if I run `lua5.3` in a terminal with the following code

```
 % lua5.3            
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> 
>   pip=io.popen("git log --format=oneline -1 --abbrev=16 --abbrev-commit -q | cut -d' ' -f1")
>   gitid=pip:read("l")
>   pip:close()
true    exit    0
> gitid
03aa650c1bbd20c3
> type(gitid)
string
```

it works as I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaTeX version 1.07.0 uses Lua 5.2 by default and in Lua 5.2 you have to use `read'*l'` instead of `read'l'`. (For compatibility, `read'*l'` still works with Lua 5.3)

So you can either add the `*` to the `read` argument or switch to `luatex53` (LuaTex with Lua 5.3) if it is installed.

For `:read`, the argument `l` or `*l` is the default, so another option is to not pass any argument:
(Additionally I added `local` to avoid the global variable `pip` and `--no-color` because e.g. on my system `git log` outputs color escape sequences otherwise)

```
% file lx.tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
  local pip=io.popen("git log --no-color --format=oneline -1 --abbrev=16 --abbrev-commit -q | cut -d' ' -f1")
  gitid=pip:read()
  pip:close()
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\mygitid}{\luadirect{tex.print(gitid)}}

The gitid is \mygitid
\end{document}
```